# Birt PostgreSQL - stored procedure dataset

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, birt

Can anybody help me with passing args to a stored procedure in birt dataset? When I try to run a report, I always get this exception:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot set preparedStatement parameter string value.
SQL error #1: Index of column is out of bounds: 1, column count: 0.
 ;
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Index of column is out of bounds: 1, column count: 0.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.setString(Statement.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.setString(OdaQuery.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doSetString(PreparedStatement.java:4422)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4031)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setParameterValue(PreparedStatement.java:3235)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setParameterValue(PreparedStatement.java:3171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.setInputParameterBinding(DataSourceQuery.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.addParameterDefns(DataSourceQuery.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.prepare(DataSourceQuery.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.prepareOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1875)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:75)
    at cz.dantem.fast.vm.birt.reports.ExecuteReport$1.run(ExecuteReport.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Index sloupece je mimo rozsah: 1, počet sloupců: 0.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:53)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:118)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2184)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1303)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1289)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.setString(Statement.java:651)
    ... 30 more
5.11.2011 17:03:47 org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement retrySetParameterValue
SEVERE: Cannot set input parameter.
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Cannot set the string value (LP) to parameter 1.
Cannot set preparedStatement parameter string value.
SQL error #1: Index of column is out of bounds: 1, column count: 0.

    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.handleException(PreparedStatement.java:4835)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doSetString(PreparedStatement.java:4427)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4031)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setParameterValue(PreparedStatement.java:3235)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setParameterValue(PreparedStatement.java:3171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.setInputParameterBinding(DataSourceQuery.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.addParameterDefns(DataSourceQuery.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.prepare(DataSourceQuery.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.prepareOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1875)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:75)
    at cz.dantem.fast.vm.birt.reports.ExecuteReport$1.run(ExecuteReport.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot set preparedStatement parameter string value.
SQL error #1: Index sloupece je mimo rozsah: 1, počet sloupců: 0.
 ;
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Index sloupece je mimo rozsah: 1, počet sloupců: 0.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.setString(Statement.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.setString(OdaQuery.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doSetString(PreparedStatement.java:4422)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Index sloupece je mimo rozsah: 1, počet sloupců: 0.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:53)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:118)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2184)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1303)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1289)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.setString(Statement.java:651)
    ... 30 more
5.11.2011 17:03:47 org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.excel.ExcelEmitter needOutputInMasterPage
```

Comment: I call my function with select * from procedureName('?'). Procedure return data table and has one input parameter - text

Comment: What is the type of the parameter of your stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a type mismatch with the type that BIRT parameter expect and the type that you pass (String).

If you have used text as parameter type in your stored procedure usually the corresponding type in Java/JDBC is java.sql.Types.CLOB .

Comment: I tryed to change param type to varchar(50), but error is the same